# Index out of range error even though number of values matches number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set some images to image views in a tableview, and I have the number of rows set to `return keys.count`, which after printing is confirmed to be `5`, which is perfect.

Now in `cellForRowAt` I get the `images` in an array, then attempt to set the images to my cell's image view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stockCell", for: indexPath) as! StockCell

        let stock = stockData[keys[indexPath.row]]!

        var images = [String]()
        stock.news.forEach { images.append($0.image) }
        print("\n\nNumber of Images: \(images.count)\n\n\n")

        if let companyImageUrl = URL(string: images[indexPath.row]) {
            ImageService.getImage(url: companyImageUrl) { (image) in
                cell.companyLogoImageView.image = image
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

I put a print statement in there to print the `images.count` (there should be 5), but the console shows 2, then 5 (x3), then 2 again - this is causing the index out of range error presumably, it's seeing 2 when there should be 5:

[image]

Why is `images.count` showing `2` in the first and last spots, but `5` in the rest?

EDIT: Rest of code

Fetching the data (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
    fetchData(url: stockApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<[String:Stock]>) -> (Void) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let object):
            self.stockData = object
            self.keys = Array(object.keys)
        print("stockData: \n\n\(self.stockData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Data is set to a dictionary, with a separate array for the keys:

```
var stockData = [String:Stock]()
var keys = [String]()
```

Structs for decoding JSON:

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let aapl, fb, msft, tsla, goog: Stock

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case aapl = "AAPL"
        case fb = "FB"
        case msft = "MSFT"
        case tsla = "TSLA"
        case goog = "GOOG"
    }
}

struct Stock: Decodable {
    let quote: Quote
    let news: [News]
}

struct Quote: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let companyName: String
    let latestPrice: Double
}

struct News: Decodable {
    let url: String
    let image: String
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, how are we supposed to know what `stock.news` contains?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure if that part was necessary, I edited my question to add the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add another print and make sure that the quantity of news is also different for each row. Then find out why it is different.

```
stock.news.forEach { images.append($0.image) }
print("\n\nNumber of Images: \(images.count)\n\n\n")
print("\n\nNumber of stock.news: \(stock.news.count)\n\n\n")
```

Comment: Ok, printing `stock.news.count` shows the same irregularity as `images.count`, except now both counts are `5`, `5`, `2`, `2`, `5`.

Comment: This isn't an answer, this is a debugging comment. Please wait until you have enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: Ok. But I thought it was. The question: "Why is images.count showing 2 in the first and last spots, but 5 in the rest?" And the answer: "because stock.news is different in each row".

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that you have 5 images because `keys.count` is 5 and this is wrong since `keys.count` tells you that you have 5 stocks in the dictionary you created from the json message.

Now each stock has an news array attached to it that I assume contains news articles/messages related to the stock for one day or similar so this array could then contain from 0 up to an infinite (not likely) amount of news articles. (in this case the number of articles ranges between 2 and 5).

Anyway, you can not rely on `keys.count` when reading the news array but instead for each array check `news.count`.

So this code needs to be changed but I am not sure how

```
if let companyImageUrl = URL(string: images[indexPath.row]) {
        ImageService.getImage(url: companyImageUrl) { (image) in
            cell.companyLogoImageView.image = image
        }
}
```

Will you show all images? then you need to surround this with a loop somehow but I get the feeling you only want to show one image so maybe change `URL(string: images[indexPath.row])` to `URL(string: images[0])`